# json_decode doesn't decode array properties

Tags: php, json

I have this json

```
{
    "name": "Default",
    "url": "{controller}\/{action}",
    "params":
    [{
        "controller": "Home",
        "action": "index"
    }]
}
```

I wanted to reconstruct the original object, but `json_decode()` gave me this

```
object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(7) "Default"
  ["url"]=>
  string(21) "{controller}/{action}"
  ["params"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
      ["controller"]=>
      string(4) "Home"
      ["action"]=>
      string(5) "index"
    }
  }
}
```

Given that I don't know what it will be in there, because params depend on the url, I only know that my object will have `name`, `url` and `params` properties.
Is there a dynamic way to set `params` as an array?

```
object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(7) "Default"
  ["url"]=>
  string(21) "{controller}/{action}"
  ["params"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["controller"]=>
      string(4) "Home"
    ["action"]=>
      string(5) "index"
  }
}
```

Comment: You might consider passing the second argument to your json decode

Comment: Or you could do `$myDecodedObject->params = (array) $myDecodedObject->params[0];`

Comment: Second one was the answer, thank you

Comment: you could also iterate through params key

Comment: I would keep the whole thing as an array an pass it into a Collection object that implements ArrayAccess and use __get() + __set()  to treat the array as an object as well.